# Can a csh script be made to "Not Execute" the date command in an echo statement

Tags: cron, echo, csh

I have a cron task that captures log files every six hours. We have a post installation script that executes after we do an install and this script builds the crontab. It is a csh script that uses the echo command and the >> redirection operator to add commands to the crontab. This is how the cron task is added to the crontab in the post installation csh script:

```
echo " 00    00,06,12,18  *  *  *   csh -c 'find last 6 hrs of modified files and tar/zip them' >> crontab
```

I want to put a date and time in the tar.gz file name so I used "date" like this to create the tar/zip filename:

```
/mnt/dir1/dir2/archive/filename_${HOST}_`date +/%Y_/%j_/%H_%M`.tar.gz
```

Unfortunately, the echo command in the post install script executes the date command and my crontab entry ends up with the time of "Right Now" in it (i.e. /mnt/dir1/dir2/archive/filename_hostname_2024_050_16_11.tar.gz). Instead of getting a crontab that creates a new archive file every six hours, I get a cron task that creates a new file every six hours with the same name as the one before.

Is there a way to make the csh 'echo' command not execute the 'date' command?

Comment: 1). I can't believe that `....filename_${HOST}_'date +/%Y_/%j_/%H_%M'.tar.gz` is producing the output you claim. Surely you mean to use back-ticks surrounding your `date ...` cmd, like `...filename_${HOST}_\`date +/%Y_/%j_/%H_%M\`.tar.gz`. 2) you need to come up with a way to delay the evaluation of the back-tics'd command. I don't have time to research now, maybe escaping the back-ticks in your command with the `"\"` char (no dbl-quotes). will work. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, yes I am using back ticks.

Comment: First, `$(...)` is a bit clearer than backticks. Second, `echo "Date: $(date)"` will execute `date`, but `echo "Date: \$(date)"` will output `Date: $(date)`, which I think is what you want.

Comment: When I type in echo "Date: $(date)" I get "Variable syntax." and it does not execute. This is on an AIX machine if that matters.

Comment: `csh` only supports back-tick cmd-substitution. Would be much easier problem to solve in another shell.

Comment: This entire system runs as a csh

Comment: Now the question is ... is your "`csh -c 'find last 6 hrs of modified files and tar/zip them'`" is ... a series of shell cmds, or the `/path/to/script_for_file_last_6...` ?? I you can use a `/path/to/script/...` your problem can easily be solved by creating the file inside the script, rather than in the crontab entry.

Comment: I did find one solution and that was to cut the echo into multiple strings by ending the first string before the first backtick and then single quoting the backticked date and then follow that up with double quotes again. Like this:

    echo "first part of string"'`date and format`'"third part of string"

it isn't pretty since its a long string but it works.

Comment: Your workflow is still unclear to me. "*Instead of getting a crontab that creates a new archive file every six hours, I get a cron task that creates a new file every six hours with the same name as the one before."*. So do you have a script that write a crontab entry and inserts it in the crrontab (thus executing the `date` cmd when you insert the record, rather than executing the `date` cmd when you are creating the file? In any case you need to delay evaluation of the `date` cmd.

Comment: No, I have a script that runs once at software install. This script adds the command to the crontab. When it adds the command to the crontab the command has 2024_050_16_11.tar.gz as part of the zip filename it will create. I want the command to have `date . . .` instead. Because of this, the cron task builds the same file ( or same file name) of 2024_050_16_11.tar.gz every six hours instead of dynamically using date to name the file every six hours. At the end of 24 hours I have one file instead of four.

Comment: I want the cron task to have '`date +/%Y_/%j_/%H_%M`' in it instead of an actual date of 2024_ etc.

Comment: So you need to include the exact code that is creating the problem entry in the body of your question. I recommend to use `printf "%s" "0 00,06,12,18  *  *  *   csh -c \'... "\\`date ...\\`"...\'" >> crontab.entry` will get you close.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256958/discussion-between-shellter-and-qman).